# Migrating an Adobe/Macromedia Contribute Publishing Services server, users not recognised

Tags: adobe, content-management, jrun, web

I have to migrate an existing installation of Contribute Publishing Services server to another machine.

**Problem Context**
I have installed a fresh copy of the CPS server software. Adjusted the server.xml file to reflect the new environment. I have logged in and linked this new instance to the same instance of open LDAP that the original server is chatting to and verified the connection and returned valid data.

I have also migrated the

- database folder
- sites folder
- ckm.xml file

( As per the Adobe Knowledge base article 1238b09)
I can log into the CPS server management inteface and view the basic information about each site under management.
I can get the Contribute Client to connect to the server and authenticate me against the open LDAP server.

**Actual Problem**
When I make a connection to the new server instance with the contribute client and request the sites.

```
connect:address:port/contribute
```

I get a message saying that the system has no new sites for me.
Each of the sites in the sites folder has a user directory and that user directory has the correct identifiers for the users. These identifiers are actually the email addresses returned through open LDAP.

Does anybody have any experience with CPS and have an idea what might be going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am answering my own question here for the benefit of this community.**
Have done some serious poking I have discovered that the new installation of CPS was unable to find the site database. This was revealed in the error log for the JRUN server.

The instructions from Macromedia(Adobe) in the Knowledge Base indicate that you need to conserve a file called ckm.xml when migrating. This file resides in the
`installation directory\jrun4\servers\contribute-wps\contribute\WEB-INF\config\ directory.`

This XML file needed to be edited as it made reference to a different drive letter in it's paths to the managed sites database (as the original installation was on an e:\ drive). Having hacked this file I have found that I can connect the contribute client to the server and get my sites loaded.

NOTE: I figure that I may have to hack the .csi files that are stored in he _mm folder in the web root for CPS managed site as the DNS address for the CPS server has now changed.

My mistake was to trust the MS file search tool initially as I had done a brute force search against the entire (new) installation directory for a reference to the old path and come up with nothing.

Goodluck to anybody else still using Contribute Publishing Services and I hope this tidbit of information will be of use to someone else in the interether!

Gus